# Insertar nodo en una posicion en una lista simple enlazada C++

Tags: c++

Buenas tengo una lista simple enlazada en la que debo insertar un nodo en una posición especifica, pero no logro dar con la solución porque se me inserta en una posición que no quiero y no comprendo que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, hasta aquí llevo la función:

```
//TO DO: implementar el procedimiento
template <class T> void ListaSimpleEnlazada<T>::insertarNodo(T dato, int posicion) {
    if(posicion >= 0 && posicion < _numeroNodos ){
        Nodo* nuevoNodo = new Nodo;
        //...
        nuevoNodo ->dato = dato;

        if (posicion == 0) {
            //..
            nuevoNodo -> siguiente = _cabeza;
            _cabeza = nuevoNodo;
        }else {
            //...
            Nodo* temporal = _cabeza;
            for(int i= 1; i <= _numeroNodos +1 ;i ++){
                if( posicion == i){
                    nuevoNodo ->siguiente =  temporal->siguiente;
                    temporal  ->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
                    cout<< "Iterador: "<<i;
                }
                cout<<"\n posicion: "<<i<<endl;
                
            }
            //nuevoNodo -> siguiente =  ; 
            
            
        }
        //...
        _numeroNodos +=1;
    }else{
        cout<< "Index " << posicion <<"fuera de rango" << endl;
    }
}
```

Aqui hago el llamado:

```
    ListaSimpleEnlazada<int> nuevaLista;
    
    int numero = 1, num2= 0, num3 = 2, num4=4, num5 =5;
    
    nuevaLista.insertarNodo(num2);
    nuevaLista.insertarNodo(numero);
    nuevaLista.insertarNodo(num3);
    nuevaLista.insertarNodo(num4);
    nuevaLista.insertarNodo(num5);
    nuevaLista.imprimirLista();   //IMPRIMO LOS VALORES INSERTADOS
    nuevaLista.insertarNodo(3,4); //INSERTO EL NUMERO 2 EN POSICION 3
    nuevaLista.imprimirLista();   //IMPRIMO LA NUEVA LISTA CON EL NODO INERTADO
    
}
```

siempre se me inserta en una posición y nunca cambia, así siempre se inserta en posición 2 y aunque la cambie no se mueve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicializas la variable `temporal` pero nunca cambia por lo tanto te mantienes en el mismo nodo.

Sugiero que lo hagas de esta forma (ahora `temporal` se llama `nodoAnterior`:

```
Nodo* nodoAnterior = _cabeza;

for (int i = 1; i <= _numeroNodos; i++){
    if (posicion == i)
        break;

    nodoAnterior = nodoAnterior->siguiente;
}

nuevoNodo->siguiente = nodo->siguiente;
nodo->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##nVJRboMwDP3PKaxOreig09hUaRqlR9gJ9kMhZdZKgkLoplU9O0tCAoVWU9d8gBw/v7xnOy3LRZ6mTXOHLN3VGYVVJTPkDx9rQiop6lTCG884HAiog0xClkgemUgn7qHCvEbKJI3IMSKkvUyTDf1JIAZGvwwuIrqW1QUVXMeVyoUdvN5JLLg3P5zwJvW3wrRE7XtbLsDTNKgSj5FBzGb6t1j3KgB93xLp09KMMCZ7NF9BZS2YBij9hOw5ZpDkguaJ8JzdgS5W072xMHBnAH1qsdZ1CtF3q0ueCDE@2lrXgmG2K3IcXf98v9eLrKJCWsElrzBFzgK4Wf7/1VvultbN7HxooZoOrOJTH@N54RY8ZwHiGHDepfTZCJp8WmqjyzoZKnMD/kv6xRJ2DrtuAkUpsEBxwwqPG6CImNx6k2n2CtPsnU3UIIN2gc0wo6tX2zEpjrmRqh8uEmROpd1z8JaW1S3@8yh@snFv08Zu8cIAXsZ3ywDC8ELhsWl@AQ).

Es posible que el resultado difiera ya que cargaste solo una parte del código y tuve que escribir algunas funciones.

Comment: Me podrías explicar un poco lo de mantener el mismo nodo, es que ya había intentado lo de tu respuesta, pero me sigue pasando lo mismo en este caso se queda en la posición 1 y ya no en la 2 y no cambia.

Comment: A qué te refieres por mantener el mismo nodo?

Comment: Es que habias mencionado que me mantenia en el mismo nodo y por eso no cambiaba.

Comment: Mira tu código original e identifica las líneas en las que asignas la variable `temporal`. Es solo una, la de inicialización. Para avanzar de nodo necesitas usar la instrucción `temporal = temporal->siguiente`.

Comment: Eso lo había probado y me daba un error, ahora revise el código que me facilitaste, corregí las cosas pero no estoy muy seguro de cual era el error porque de un momento a otro ya funcionó, antes  lo había compilado muchas veces e insertaba un nodo en una posición incorrecta.